# How to remove properties from a class

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm querying my database via EF, and I return a `List<T>`.

I use code similar too

```
var result = (from m in model
select new
{
    Id = m.Id,
    Dependency = m.Dependency,
    Description = m.Description
}).ToList();
```

This works great but now,  I may or may not want to show `Dependency` or `Description` (depends on the value of a parameter passed to the function). And there are actually about 10 properties, I've only shown 2 to keep the code small

I don't know how I can remove the value or properties.

I can't have if/else statements when I create the anonymous class, and since it is anonymous all properties are read only so I can't use the fact it's `IQueryable` to just put values to null or 0!

Comment: you can't remove properties at runtime!

Comment: just set themto 'null' values?

Comment: The only solution I have is to create a new Model which mimics my anonymous class, so at least this way the results are not readonly but this seems hacky! @DanielA.White but, this may be the only solution :S

Comment: @DieterB, as I wrote, it's anonymous, meaning, the properties are read only

Comment: I agree @Hogan, but don't see how to design it. The above example has worked fine, but the user may want to hide some values. The problem is that although it's easy to hide the values in browser, if the user views the source (HTML or JSON) they can see the values. As such, I need to remove these from 'source' so to speak

Comment: I'm not sure what this has to do with viewing the source.

Comment: Looks like you lack a level of abstraction over your UI, that is responsible for your UI-specific things, something like metadata. Think about making abstraction over your grid or any UI element that you draw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var result = (from m in model
select new
{
    Id = m.Id,
    Dependency = shouldShow ? m.Dependency : null,
    Description = shouldShow ? m.Description : null
}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you want to use the Factory Model Design Pattern here.  This means you should have a class for all potential result classes.

Factory Model is covered in great detail elsewhere and can be found with a google search -- you create a class that given parameters will "produce" an object of the type required by the input parameters.